# parsing informations from an ostringstream

Tags: c++, string, parsing, dictionary, vector

I have this ostringstream that contains informations about folders and files, the list of folders and their informations starts from "folders:" and ends before "files:", whereas the list of files start from the line that contains "files:" until the end of the stream, my goal is to generate from that ostringstream two vectors, one for folders and the other for files, inside those vectors I want to use a map for each folder or file to store the informations relative to them,

example : a vector "MyFolders" that contains 3 items of type `map<string,string>`, inside this map
MyFolders[0]["id"] would return for example "109"
MyFiles[0]["name"] would return for example "a_file.jpg"

content of the ostringstream to parse :

```
folders:
:
id: 109
parent_id: 110
name: first_folder
// other informations about a folder ...
path: /1/105/110/
:
id: 110
parent_id: 103
name: second_folder
// other informations about a file ...
path: /1/105/
files:
:
id: 26
parent_id: 105
name: a_file.jpg
size: 7345
// other informations about a file ...
path: /1/105/
:
id: 69
parent_id: 105
name: another_file.txt
// other informations about a file ...
size: 7345
path: /1/105/
```

Comment: And where are you getting problem? Did you even try anything?

Comment: I don't know what functions/tools that help me to extract informations from lines, else I will be able to think of the algorithm and then write the code

Comment: if you want to read a line you can use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: Thank you, and if I want to extract from a string like "id: 105", "id" and "105" (without the space " 105") what can you avise me ? I want to do something like this MyFolder[0][string_that_contains_id] = string_that_contains_105

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use 2 vectors like

```
vector<int,int,char*,char*>file and //for saving id,parent id,name and path
vector<int,int,char*,char*>folder
```

and used `istream::getline` to check whether this line is `"file" or "folder"`

For getting more about getline and file functions you can check the implementation and logic from the link i have given in comment section.

Comment: thank you, but I prefer using string for the id,p_id etc... because I use them in HTTP requests (easier to treat as strings), otherwise, I know using vectors with one type, like vector<string> example; I don't know that type of vectors with myltiple types

Comment: Okay I understood what have you said, I will try it